# Why WebRTC for Android can be only built on Linux and not Mac OS X?

Tags: android, macos, webrtc

I know that `chromium` does not support the android build on mac.
I want to figure out the details why the `WebRTC` for android can not be built on mac.

which third-party or libs does not support？

Is there any tips to do some patch?.

I am working on the latest git repository.

Thanks.

Comment: Why haven't you looked at [this](http://blog.gaku.net/building-webrtc-for-android-on-mac/)?

Comment: @CoolMind,I did read the post .The linked article point out that WebRTC for android can only be built on Linux.The source code can't be built on Mac directly. thanks,anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it couldn't be built on Mac.